# How to handle XMPP subscribtions with SleekXMPP or python i general

Tags: python, xmpp, xmppframework

Here is my use-case:

1. User clicks link on webpage saying: "Follow this person on XMPP"
2. Script is initiated and gets (based on registered data) the requestors username and password and starts.
3. The subscription request is sent. If a subscription is already sent, the script should not send another one. If the subscription was rejected, the script should notify the user.
4. The script should then exit

Here is my code so far, using [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki):

```
import sys, sleekxmpp, logging

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#This is hardcoded here, for illustration. 
jid = 'hermans@******.com/Work'
password = '********'
targetjid = 'simena@*******.com/Work'

class SubscribeWorker(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

    def start(self, event):
        self.send_presence(pto=targetjid, ptype='subscribe')
        self.get_roster()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=5,format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    xmpp = SubscribeWorker(jid, password)
    if xmpp.connect():
        xmpp.process(threaded=False)
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("Unable to connect.")
```

This sends a request successfully, but it does not take height for any existing request or subscription status. Does anyone have example code on subscribe/unsubscribe handling with XMPP?
And I've tried to understand the wiki and code examples - I really have, I'm just stuck at the moment with this code.

Thanks in advance, for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, try putting a like like [xmpp:simena@*******.com?subscribe](http://xmpp%3asimena@%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a.com?subscribe) on the web page, which should do the right thing in your existing desktop client.